# User registered but not authenticated after login

Tags: python, django, django-authentication

i am creating simple website in Django, i am a beginner. Now i am creating registration and login options, but authentication does not work for me (i know it because in logged_in.html there is not displaying username name).

views.py

```
from django.shortcuts import render, render_to_response, get_object_or_404, redirect
from django.http import HttpResponse
from django.contrib import auth
from django.contrib.auth import authenticate, login
from django.template.context_processors import csrf
from django.http import HttpResponseRedirect
from django.template import RequestContext
from MySite.forms import RegistrationForm
from django.contrib.auth.forms import AuthenticationForm
from django.contrib.auth.models import User

def register_user(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = RegistrationForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            form.save()
            return HttpResponseRedirect('register_success')

    args = {}
    args.update(csrf(request))

    args['form'] = RegistrationForm()
    return render_to_response('register_user.html', args)

def register_success(request):
    return render_to_response('register_success.html')

def login_user(request):
    login_user = {}
    login_user.update(csrf(request))
    return render_to_response('login_user.html', login_user)

def auth_view(request):
    username = request.POST.get('username', '')
    password = request.POST.get('password', '')
    user = auth.authenticate(username=username, password=password)

    if user is not None:
        auth.login(request, user)
        return redirect('logged_in')
    else:
        return HttpResponseRedirect('invalid_login')

def logged_in(request):
    return render_to_response('logged_in.html',
                              {'full_name': request.user.username})`
```

urls.py

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import include, path
from django.contrib.auth import views

urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path('MySite/', include('MySite.urls')),
    path('accounts/', include('django.contrib.auth.urls')),
]
```

MySite.urls.py

```
from django.urls import path
from . import views

urlpatterns = [
    path('', views.index, name='index'),
    path('register_user', views.register_user, name='register_user'),
    path('register_success', views.register_success, name='register_success'),
    path('login_user', views.login_user, name='login_user'),
    path('authorized', views.auth_view, name='authorized'),
    path('logout', views.logout, name='logout'),
    path('logged_in', views.logged_in, name='logged_in'),
    path('invalid_login', views.invalid_login, name='invalid_login'),
```

logged_in.html

```
{% extends "base.html" %}

{% block content %}

    <h2>Hello {{full_name}}, you are logged! </h2>
    <p>Kliknij <a href= "{% url 'logout' %}">tutaj</a> aby się wylogować.</p>
    {% if user.is_authenticated %}
            <a href="{% url 'logout' %}">logout</a>
    {% else %}
            <a href="{% url 'login_user' %}">login</a> / <a href="{% url 'register_user' %}">register</a>
    {% endif %}

{% endblock %}
```

settings.py

```
"""
Django settings for myproject project.

Generated by 'django-admin startproject' using Django 2.2.9.

For more information on this file, see
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/topics/settings/

For the full list of settings and their values, see
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/settings/
"""

import os

# Build paths inside the project like this: os.path.join(BASE_DIR, ...)
BASE_DIR = os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__)))


# Quick-start development settings - unsuitable for production
# See https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/howto/deployment/checklist/

# SECURITY WARNING: keep the secret key used in production secret!
SECRET_KEY = '4w@82m1#)3=+8i7wt@ioxq#-0nhn3nyl@83utekwc+&#cin)%p'

# SECURITY WARNING: don't run with debug turned on in production!
DEBUG = True

ALLOWED_HOSTS = ['127.0.0.1', '.pythonanywhere.com']


# Application definition

INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'MySite',
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
]

MIDDLEWARE = [
    'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
]

ROOT_URLCONF = 'myproject.urls'

TEMPLATES = [
    {
        'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
        'DIRS': [os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'myproject/templates')],
        'APP_DIRS': True,
        'OPTIONS': {
            'context_processors': [
                'django.template.context_processors.debug',
                'django.template.context_processors.request',
                'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
                'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
            ],
        },
    },
]





WSGI_APPLICATION = 'myproject.wsgi.application'


# Database
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/settings/#databases

DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.sqlite3',
        'NAME': os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'db.sqlite3'),
    }
}


# Password validation
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/settings/#auth-password-validators

AUTH_PASSWORD_VALIDATORS = [
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.UserAttributeSimilarityValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.MinimumLengthValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.CommonPasswordValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.NumericPasswordValidator',
    },
]


# Internationalization
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/topics/i18n/

LANGUAGE_CODE = 'pl-pl'

TIME_ZONE = 'Europe/Warsaw'

USE_I18N = True

USE_L10N = True

USE_TZ = True


# Static files (CSS, JavaScript, Images)
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/howto/static-files/

STATIC_URL = '/static/'
STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static')
```

forms.py

```
from django import forms
from .models import *
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from django.contrib.auth.forms import UserCreationForm

class RegistrationForm(UserCreationForm):
    email = forms.EmailField(required=True)

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(RegistrationForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)

        for fieldname in ['username', 'password1', 'password2']:
            self.fields[fieldname].help_text = None

    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = ('username', 'email', 'password1', 'password2')

    def save(self, commit=True):
        user = super(RegistrationForm, self).save(commit=False)
        user.email = self.cleaned_data['email']

        if commit:
            user.save()

        return user
```

I followed instructions from tutorial but it does not work. Maybe someone could help me? It is Django 2.2.9

Answer (score 1):

You are not logging the user in your registration view. Here is how to login the user:

```py
from django.contrib.auth import login as auth_login
...


def register_user(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = RegistrationForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            user = form.save()  # get user instance
            auth_login(request, user)  # login user
            return HttpResponseRedirect('register_success')

    args = {}
    args.update(csrf(request))

    args['form'] = RegistrationForm()
    return render_to_response('register_user.html', args)
```

Comment: Thank you for yours fast response :) Yes i decided to not log my user in after registration, i have redirecting to login template where user can login after registration. Then when i log in and i delete from template authentication if, i see user login. I also used your idea but then i get an error "name 'user' is not defined" :(

Comment: @ToJa so your ``auth_view`` is the one that's not working?

Comment: Yes Pedro it looks like this, but in auth_view i have formula which is redirecting me to template logged_in when user is not None and it works, so i am really confused why it is not working - i looked in ther topics but there weren't any similar problems.

Comment: @ToJa you have to pass the request to ``authenticate`` in your auth_view https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/contrib/auth/#django.contrib.auth.backends.ModelBackend.authenticate

Comment: Thank you, isn't this line responsible for this? "user = auth.authenticate(username=username, password=password)" I think it should do the job but it does not work

Comment: @ToJa when you register your user, is the user field ``is_active`` True? That may be the issue.

Comment: I didn't create model for this, i just implemented it as you see above, i heard it will also work. Is possible that when i will create a model for registration it will work and user will be authenticated?

Comment: @ToJa the User Model by default has a the field ``is_active`` you should check if your registered users are active: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/contrib/auth/#django.contrib.auth.models.User.is_active